# Access XMLHttpRequest data in CakePhp controller

Tags: javascript, cakephp, xmlhttprequest

I have this piece of code:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
              var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                request.open('POST','/leandwell/processData', true);
                request.send(formData);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                       // OK

                       alert(request.responseText);
            } else {
                       // not OK
                       alert('failure!');
            }
        }
};
```

With this function in my controller:

```
public function processData(){
        $this->autoRender = false;
                $data = $this->request->data;

            return json_encode($data['address']);
    }
```

But it's just alerting **Undefined index address** meanwhile I have `<input type="text" name="address">` inside my form. Is their another way I can access this data correctly in my controller method.
I am actually using `XMLHttpRequest` because the form has input type file, because I need to upload a file along with it.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your `formData` doesn't match what Cake expects. Make sure the form data you send equals that HTML attribute `name="data[address]"` instead of `name="address"`.

Also instead of doing `return json_encode($data['address']);` [read XML and Json Views in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).